# SVG Capture Specific Area

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to capture specific area of an svg using XML or programmatically and export the capture out as an svg too? Like the following example
Full SVG Image
[image: Full Svg]

Captured left arm svg

[image: Captured]

Comment: Use a clipPath to clip the drawing.

Comment: Or if the area is always rectangular, you can just adjust the `viewBox` so that it shows only the desired area.